# appropriate IDE for Angular2, Play and scala

Tags: angularjs, playframework

My technology stack is Angular 2, Scala and mongoDB. So far I have used IntelliJ (Community Edition) and Play for scala/mongodb for backend stuff. How could I write front code in Angular 2 using IntelliJ and play? Or shall I migrate to some other IDE? This is a personal project, I do not want to purchase a commercial IDE.

Added this to explain my issue.

In Play/Scala/IntelliJ, to receive a request and send a response, I code like this

```
def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Welcome to SalesWorkspace")(loginForm))

  }
```

The route file will be something like follows

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
```

the index.html page is defined in Play/IntelliJ and is part of IntelliJ's project. It will look something like this

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:font-variant="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:background-color="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")">
</head>
<body>
.
. <!-- regular html stuff-->
.
</body>
</html>
```

To run above code, I'll simply start play server (play debug run) and execute Run from IntellJ. In the background, both IntelliJ and Play would together and will submit the index page when I visit localhost:9000.

I programmed in Angular in similar way without using IntelliJ. I used sublime to code, used the quickstart package from angular.io website and ran `npm start`. I am guessing that npm started its own server and handing all the routing etc for me.

Now I want to integrate the frontend code I wrote in Angular (and tested using npm start) with the backend code I wrote in Play/IntelliJ. I do not have the commercial edition of IntelliJ. How do I write index.html in Angular and make it talk to the server started by Play/IntelliJ.

Comment: you will not have javascript plugin for intellij in Community edition, you can use sublime, atom, brackets etc.. for dev

Comment: I have used sublime for standalone Angular development (no backend). That worked fine. My issue is how to make the angular code talk to 'Play/Scala' code. Without Angular (just html), I would simply start server in IntelliJ IDE and the server, routing etc would be taken care of. If I integrate Angular, I guess I would need to transpile the Typescript code to JS etc etc (I do not understand many of these bits unfortunately)

Comment: you can run or develop your scala code in intellij and to connect angular app to the server, you can run angular in a node server or if using a task runner(grunt) you can run your angular app (grunt server)

Comment: I have no clue how to actually do what you just recommended. Normally (without angular, just HTML code) I'll go to my project directory and type `play debug run` to start Play server. Then I'll start IntelliJ and Run my project. On opening url `http://localhost:9000/`, I would see my app. For Angular (using sublime, no backend), I execute `npm start`, a browser window gets opened with url `http://localhost:3000`. How do I remove my html code from IntelliJ and 'connect' the angular app (which now has the HTML code) to play code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to develop an Angular application. In order to watch, compile and serve it you can use the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) which makes your life much easier.

For Scala I would just keep using IntelliJ, keeping it separated from the front-end code.

Comment: how do I make the Angular UI (made in Visual or sublime) talk to the scala code (written using IntelliJ)? To run my app, I'll need a web server. I can use the one provided in IntelliJ which runs on localhost:9000. This server will need the UIs (angular html) to provide new pages (index etc.) to the browser. But Angular files are not part of IntelliJ project.

Comment: I have made the question verbose. I hope it will help in explaining my issue.

Comment: you can run your server and client separately. You can run your server using intellij as you did before and then run your client using the AngularCLI `ng serve` command.